# Unable to deploy any applet built by NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

I'm new to Java. I'm unable to deploy any applet on a html page and constantly getting InvocationTargetException. To illustrate this, here is an example:

My applet has only one class that has a main. All the code are generated by NetBeans and the GUI contains only one button:

```
package javaapplication;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")


   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(317, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(266, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration      
}
```

It compiles and runs smoothely, within NetBeans. Now I clean and build the .jar file. Here's the MANIFEST.MF, which looks fine to me:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_10-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: javaapplication.NewJFrame
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <applet archive="JavaApplication.jar" width="300" height="300" code="javaapplication.NewJFrame"/>

    </body>

</html>
```

I've put them in the same directory and set permission properly as well. Now when I try to open my index.html which is placed on server, it gives InvocationTargetException, on both newest versions of Firefox and Chrome.

I'm tried many different things like creating a another class that has a main, or using Jnlp but no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not see an applet in your code.

```
package javaapplication;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
[...]
```

**Create the Java project from scratch.** (Netbeans)

- Choose File > New Project (Ctrl-Shift-N) (MyTestApplet).
- Under Categories, select Java.
- Select Java Class Library under Projects.
- Click Finish.
- Create the applet source file
- Right-click the MyTestApplet project node in the Projects window and select New > Other (Ctrl-N).
- Under Categories, select Java.
- Select Swing GUI Forms > JApplet Form.
- Click Next.
- Under Class Name, type `NewJApplet` .
- Under Package, type `javaapplication` .
- Click Finish.

The IDE creates the applet source file in the specified package. The applet source file opens and the GUI Editor opens.

- Drag an Button to the Gui.

The Source NewJapplet.java should look something like:

```
package javaapplication;

public class NewJApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {


    @Override
    public void init() {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(182, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(139, 139, 139))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(232, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;

}
```

- Run `Build`

In the dist folder now is `MyTestApplet.jar`

- Copy the .jar to the server in a folder `MyTestApplet`
- Copy following .html to the server, same folder `MyTestApplet`

use this html file.

- Change classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-**0016**-0000-0000-ABCDEFFEDCBA" width="300" height="300"> 
  pointing to your Java Version
- **0017**

AppletPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Applet Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Applet Demo</h1>
    <h2>This applet has been deployed with the object tag</h2>
    <object 
    classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-0000-ABCDEFFEDCBA" width="300" height="300">
    <PARAM name="code" value="javaapplication.NewJApplet">
    <PARAM name="archive"  value="MyTestApplet.jar">
    <comment>
      <embed code="javaapplication.NewJApplet.class"
             width="300"
             height="300"
             archive="MyTestApplet.jar"
             type="application/x-java-applet">
        <noembed>
          No Java Support.
        </noembed>
      </embed>
    </comment>
  </object>

  </body>
</html>
```

- in your browser type the url: `http://localhost/MyTestApplet/AppletPage.html`

and voila:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, do I need a main function in my JApplet class? If no, how do I test it? If yes, what should I put in that class? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, no main in a applet. To test, right click on `NewJapplet.java` and debug as file.